# Loop through Twitter followers with rtweet package in R

Tags: r, loops, twitter

I have a list of Twitter IDs that used a specific hashtag and now I'm trying to make a network graph to see who they follow. With the brand new **rtweet** package, the idea is that for each `user_id` I use `get_friends` function and end up with two-column table - *userids* | *following*.

The problem is that instead of two columns, I end up with just one. Here's what I'm doing based on similar questions:

```
#this is where the ids list comes from
head(ids)
user_id             freq
2953382183           291
2832407758           178
522476436            149
773707421579677696   117
1296286704           113
773555423970529280   113

#for each user_id, get_friends() show me who the user is following
userids <- ids[1,1]
following <- get_friends(userids)
head(following)
               ids
         540219772
757699150507020288
        2392165598
         628569910
         576547113
         181996651

#NOW I'LL TRY TO FILL A NEW DATA FRAME FOR EACH "user_id" WITH ALL FOLLOWING "ids"

#initializing an empty data frame
final <- data.frame(userids = character(), following =character())

totalusers <- nrow(ids) #ids is a data frame where I got all `user_id`
userids <- NULL
following <- NULL
df <- NULL

for (i in 1:totalusers)
{
userids[i] <- ids[i,1]
following <- get_friends(userids[i]) #get_friends returns a data frame, by package default
df[i] <- data.frame(userids[i], following)
final <- rbind(final, df[i])
}
```

Does anyone know how I append *following* variable to this data frame? Many thanks.

Comment: You probably should read the RInferno on growing objects. what you want to be doing is indexing the proper rows and columns, not creating data frames in each iteration, or similarly, using `rbind` at each iteration.

Comment: Thank you very much @shayaa. For now I will edit the post with a solution using dataframes, while I'm working on a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: No problem. It is accepted standard to provide a minimal dataset with which to test your code, as well as expected results. You will often get downvoted if you do not do so. Also, you can post a solution to your own question, you don't need to leave it as an edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a given set of id's (`ids`) you can do the following:

```
library(rtweet)
library(plyr)
ids<-c("156562085","808676983","847366544183050240")#the users id
list_of_friends<-lapply(ids,get_friends)#get all the friends' ids per each user id
names(list_of_friends)<-ids
list_of_friends2<-lapply(list_of_friends,function(y) dim(y)[1])#get the number of friends 
df1<-ldply(list_of_friends2, data.frame)#transform the data into data.frame
names(df1)<-c("user_id","following")
```

`df1` yields:

```
             user_id         following
1           156562085           339
2           808676983          1066
3  847366544183050240             0
```

Additionally in order to produce the [edge list](http://www.shizukalab.com/toolkits/sna/sna_data):

```
f1<-function(x){
  return(cbind(rep(names(list_of_friends[x]),dim(list_of_friends[[x]])
[1]),list_of_friends[[x]]))
}
l1<-lapply(names(list_of_friends),f1)
df2<-ldply(l1,data.frame)
names(df2)<-c("user_id","friend_id")
```

yielding `df2`:

```
  user_id          friend_id
1    156562085           26787673
2    156562085           18139619
3    156562085           23827692
                [...]
1403 808676983           19397785
1404 808676983           50393960
1405 808676983           113419517
```

If you add the column values from `following` in `df1` you get 1405, agreeing to `nrow(df2)`. I believe `df2` is what you wanted at a first place.

Answer (score 1):

The following piece of code works, although maybe It's not the most efficient way for large datasets.

```
for (i in 1:totalusers)
{
userids[i] <- ids[i,1]
following <- get_friends(userids[i])
final <- rbind(final, data.frame(userids=userids[i], following=following))
}
```

I ended up with this:

```
userids                    ids
2953382183           540219772
2953382183  757699150507020288
2953382183          2392165598
2953382183           628569910
2953382183           576547113
2953382183           181996651
```